# What is the proper way to say this greeting?

Tags: word-choice

I work for a customer service company. The told me that the greeting or the opening should be (Michael at your help. How can I help you?).

First of all, I think I should say (This is Michael. How can I help you?)

Second, I think there's a grammar mistake in their greeting and it should be (Michael **is** at your help. How can I help you?).

Finally, I think repeating the word "help" twice is not professional. It would be better to say (Michael is at your assistance. How can I help you?)

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"At your help" is absolutely wrong.

"At your service" would be correct but hopelessly formal & out-moded.

We really need context. 
What's the environment?

In a gym, burger bar, "Hi. I'm Mike. How can I help?"

At a funeral parlour, "My name is Michael. How may I be of assistance?"

Anywhere in between, "My name is Michael. How can I help/How can I assist you?"
Vary it a bit, which may help to keep it sounding fresher than you may feel.

Note: for call centres, keep it short.
*"Hello this is the XYZ happy fabulous company my name is Michael Smitherington I hope you're well how may I be of assistance?"*
They stopped listening after 'Hello'

Btw, don't use "This is Michael."
It sounds like you're introducing them to someone standing next to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I really appreciate it.  Now, my trainer is teaching me something wrong. Idk how to say this to her?!

Comment: Send her this QA as a link ;)

Comment: My doctor's office regularly answers with, "This is office of Dr Fred Smith, the Anytown Medical Center, an affiliate of the Foobar Medical Network, Sally Jones speaking. How can I help you?" (Names changed to protect the innocent.) Hey, I pay by the minute on my cell phone plan. I don't care.

Comment: Fortunately, my doctor now has an app ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "At your help" is grammatically incorrect. And goofy sounding.

That said, if you're just starting the job and they're paying your salary, I'd say whatever silly thing they tell you to say. When you've been there a while and you have some credibility might be a time to complain about the patter.

People don't listen to what you say when you answer the phone anyway.

At a job I had a few years back, we had a phone line installed that was only used for the computer to make outgoing calls. The phone number was not published or given to anyone because there was no reason for anyone to call. One day I was standing by the computer when the phone rang. I hesitated a moment, then picked it up and said, "Hello, wrong number."

The person at the other end just went right ahead and said, "Can I speak to Fred Jones?" or whatever the name was.

"No," I said, "This is the wrong number."

"Is this XYZ Company?" he asked.

"No," I repeated, "You have the wrong number."

He wasn't listening to anything I said at all.